# RuntimeError: No application found. Can't load tags for questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, runtime-error, flask-sqlalchemy

For course purposes we're making Stackoverflow like website using Flask. Everything worked just fine until we wanted to let users tag their questions.

We made model for that:

```
from AskMate import db


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Tag({self.name})"


class Question_Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('question.id'), nullable=False)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Question_Tag(qid:{self.question_id}, tid:{self.tag_id})"
```

Same as form for adding them:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Length


class TagForm(FlaskForm):
    tag = TextAreaField("Tag", validators=[Length(min= 1, max= 6)])
    submit = SubmitField("Post an Tag")
```

Until that moment everything worked good, User could add easily new tags and it was saved in db. We got troubled when we wanted to add choice field for them in our Question form.

```
class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField("Title",
                        validators=[DataRequired()])
    question = TextAreaField("Question",
                             validators=[DataRequired()])
    picture = FileField("Upload picture for your question (optional)",
                        validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'svg', 'bmp'])])
    question_tags = SelectMultipleField("Tags", choices=get_tags())
    submit = SubmitField("Ask Question")
    submit_edit = SubmitField("Accept Edition")
```

Problem is with that function. I tried it in several ways and always Tag.query.all() cause RuntimeError.

> RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function
> or push an application context.

```
from AskMate.tags.models import Tag


def get_tags():
    return [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in Tag.query.all()]
```

That it our init file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail

from AskMate.config import Config


db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
mail = Mail()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)

    from AskMate.answers.routes import answers
    from AskMate.users.routes import users
    from AskMate.comments.routes import comments
    from AskMate.main.routes import main
    from AskMate.tags.routes import tags
    from AskMate.questions.routes import questions
    from AskMate.errors.handlers import errors

    app.register_blueprint(answers)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(comments)
    app.register_blueprint(tags)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(questions)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)

    return app
```

and run.py

```
from AskMate import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any ideas how can we solve that problem? We tried with app_context but I'm afraid that we did something wrong or we used it in wrong placre (we tried in init and run)...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From memory, you need to run the query after the form is instantiated (right now it may be trying to run the query outside of an app context).

In your View, Something like:

```
form = QuestionForm()
form.question_tags.choices = get_tags()
```